# how to pass arguments in thread in python

Tags: python, multithreading, python-multithreading

as part of a trading application which i am developing, i need to send a parameter to a Thread. I have already referred the below links and none of these are working.

[Python Threading String Arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3221655/python-threading-string-arguments),
[How to pass arguments to thread functions in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62482050/how-to-pass-arguments-to-thread-functions-in-python),
[python threading - best way to pass arguments to threads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21429819/python-threading-best-way-to-pass-arguments-to-threads)

My code

```
order_trigger_loop_initiator = threading.Thread(target=trigger(), args=[company_data['instrument_token']])
renko_loop_initiator.start()
```

Part of the function which i am initiating as a thread

```
def RENKO_TRIMA(token):
    global ohlc_final_1min, RENKO_Final, final_position, order_quantity, RENKO, RENKO_temp, Direction, Orderid, Target_order, Target_order_id, renko_thread_running, day_profit_percent
    try:
        renko_thread_running = "YES"
        attained_profit()
        quantity()
        positions(token)
```

I have followed the suggestion in the above mentioned website and even tried to do stuff like

```
renko_loop_initiator = threading.Thread(target=RENKO_TRIMA, args=company_data['instrument_token'])
```

and

```
renko_loop_initiator = threading.Thread(target=RENKO_TRIMA, args=[company_data['instrument_token']]))
renko_loop_initiator = threading.Thread(target=RENKO_TRIMA, args=(company_data['instrument_token']))
renko_loop_initiator = threading.Thread(target=RENKO_TRIMA, args=(company_data['instrument_token'],))
```

Nothing seems to be working. the value that be sent as an argument would be 1270529

I get the below error message when i am trying any of the above methods.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/win10/PycharmProjects/Trading-Application/USD-INR.py", line 838, in on_ticks
    order_trigger_loop_initiator = threading.Thread(target=trigger(), args=[company_data['instrument_token']])
TypeError: trigger() missing 1 required positional argument: 'token'
```

Comment: trigger is not supposed to be called `threading.Thread(target=trigger, args=[company_data['instrument_token']])` remove `()` after trigger

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the error message, you are calling `trigger` instead of passing it as a function.

```
order_trigger_loop_initiator = threading.Thread(target=trigger(), ...
                                                   # uh oh ---^
```

Try passing just the function:

```
order_trigger_loop_initiator = threading.Thread(
    target=trigger, 
    args=[company_data['instrument_token']]
)
```

Answer (score 1):

You're calling `trigger` (which you haven't posted in your question, making this guesswork) immediately there:

```
order_trigger_loop_initiator = threading.Thread(
  target=trigger(),
  args=[company_data['instrument_token']],
)
```

That might work if `trigger` was a function that accepted no arguments and returned another function, but if you mean to run the `trigger` function in another thread, you'll want to remove those parentheses:

```
order_trigger_loop_initiator = threading.Thread(
  target=trigger,
  args=[company_data['instrument_token']],
)
```

Comment: i have actually put a wrong code, updated the function name which i was calling. Updated it.

Comment: it worked. How a small mistake made a whole lot of difference. With parentheses, i was calling trigger as a function which indeed will run other functions. But without parentheses, i will run the trigger independently as a different thread